# I am having issue while opening the cypress, I ma using Cypress for the first time and trying to install

Tags: windows, installation, cypress

I installed node.js and installed cypress also, but everytime I try to open cypress,  I am getting this error:

> cypress : The term 'cypress' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again. At line:1 char:1 + cypress open --browser +
> *~~~~~~~* + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (cypress:String) [],
> CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> CommandNotFoundException

I tried -> `npm run cypress:open`

and the cypress window says "Not Responsding"

Could anyone please help as I tried everything

I did try adding this in Package.json file

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress open"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to run the cypress script (npm@5.2.0 or greater is required)

```
npx cypress open
```